# How to store language tag IDs in databases, as smallint or varchar?

Tags: database, database-design, performance

I'm wondering about how to store language tag IDs (e.g. en-US).

A quick example:

```
Table l10n ( l10n_id SMALLINT, code VARCHAR(5) )  
    PK: l10n_id
    Index on code  
Table product ( product_id INT, ..language-neutral columns.. )  
    PK: product_id
Table product_l10n ( product_id INT, l10n_id SMALLINT, ..language-specific columns.. )  
    PK: product_id, l10n_id.  
    Indexes on product_id and l10n_id
```

If we use varchar IDs:

```
Table l10n ( l10n_id VARCHAR(5) )  
    PK: l10n_id
```

**1. Using smallint IDs:**

It requires to make a join with the language table:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM product a
        LEFT JOIN product_l10n b ON b.id = a.id
        LEFT JOIN l10n c ON c.id = b.id
    WHERE c.code = 'en-US';
```

**2. Using varchar IDs:**

We don't have to use the l10n table in our queries:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM product a
        LEFT JOIN product_l10n b ON (b.product_id = a.id AND b.l10n_id = 'en-US');
```

A smallint takes 2 bytes while a varchar(5) takes up to 6 bytes (in PostgreSQL, see the [doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/datatype.html)).
So I guess that all indexes (l10n pk, product_l10n pk, and product_l10n.l10n_id) will be bigger with varchar IDs. And therefore, the performances will decrease. Is that correct?

**3. Conclusion:**

Am I right in saying the more localized data we have, the less performant using varchar IDs is?
And therefore, using smallint IDs is a better design.

Comment: I finally decided to store them as SMALLINT.
And I use a custom variable to store the current language, for more info, see my other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307582/postgresql-can-one-define-a-session-variable-with-the-language-and-use-it-in-vie

Answer (score 1):

When storing `VARCHARs`, collations come into play, making index comparisons a trifle less efficient (at least in `MySQL`).

Also, in `MySQL` an key miss on a `VARCHAR` is much more expensive than an key hit.

See this article in my blog for performance:

- **[Fallback language names: `MySQL`](http://explainextended.com/2009/08/10/fallback-language-names-mysql/)**

On the other side, storing the codes in a separate table will require an extra `JOIN` that will kill all performance benefits.

So in `MySQL` it's probably worth keeping codes as `TINYINT`s, while in other systems it will be better to keep them as `VARCHAR`'s

Comment: Since language code will not be very dynamic, it is plausible for the SQL to be written without the join; you collect the relevant language code once from the table, and thereafter provide it as a parameter to the queries...well, that avoids the joins.  Gut feel: the joins should not be problematic if your DBMS has an optimizer worthy of the name.